# Setting a variable inside dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server

I've created a stored procedure i'm planning to pass a table name into to allow me to collect a URN from a control table and allocate it to the passed table by adding the existing URN (int identity) to the stored value in the control table.

Here's the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[System_IndividualURN_Processing]
    @TableName Varchar(100)

AS Begin

DECLARE @iCounter           INT,
        @NextCustomerURN    INT,
        @TSQL               Varchar(Max)

SET @TSQL = '
        SET '+@iCounter+' = COUNT(*)
        FROM  dbo.' +@TableName+'
        '

EXEC @TSQL

PRINT @iCounter

SELECT @NextCustomerURN = URN --select URN
FROM   dbo.System_NextNumbers A
where [Type] = 'NextCustomerURN'

UPDATE A
SET URN = URN + @iCounter
FROM   dbo.System_NextNumbers A
where [Type] = 'NextCustomerURN'

SET @TSQL = '

        UPDATE A
        SET           IndividualURN = URN + CONVERT(INT, @NextCustomerURN)-1
        FROM  dbo.'+@TableName+' A
        '
EXEC @TSQL

End
```

I'm receiving the following error when I execute:

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dbo.System_IndividualURN_Processing, Line 12 [Batch Start Line 2]
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '
        SET ' to data type int.

I've narrowed it down to the following statement:

```
SET @TSQL = '
        SET '+@iCounter+' = COUNT(*)
        FROM  dbo.' +@TableName+'
    '
```

Suggesting it's not possible to set the variable using dynamic SQL in this way or something is missing in the syntax.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can't access a variable inside a script with EXEC. A solution would be creating a temporary table outside the EXEC and do the insert inside, so you can select the values afterward.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a variable declared outside the current batch (unless it's passed as parameter). So trying to set `@iCounter` from within a `EXEC` will always fail.

You can switch to a temporary table, which can be accessed inside the `EXEC`. Just need to be sure to create it outside because otherwise you won't be able to select the results outside the `EXEC`.

```
DECLARE @iCounter INT
DECLARE @TSQL Varchar(Max)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CountTotals') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #CountTotals

CREATE TABLE #CountTotals (
    TableName VARCHAR(100),
    TotalRows INT)

SET @TSQL = '

    INSERT INTO #CountTotals (
        TableName,
        TotalRows)
    SELECT
        TableName = ''' + @TableName + ''',
        TotalRows = COUNT(1)
    FROM
        dbo.' + @TableName

EXEC (@TSQL)

SET @iCounter = (SELECT C.TotalRows FROM #CountTotals AS C WHERE C.TableName = @TableName)
```

Same thing will happen when you try to use `@NextCustomerURN` on the other dynamic SQL. You will have to render the `@NextCustomerURN` value as string to correctly use it.

```
SET @TSQL = '

        UPDATE A
        SET           IndividualURN = URN + CONVERT(INT, ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), @NextCustomerURN) + ''')-1
        FROM  dbo.'+@TableName+' A
        '
EXEC @TSQL
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I'll give that a try

Comment: Thank you both, I now have a working stored procedure as follows:

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use [sys.sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql)

You can parameters to this. the `@TSQL` parameter needs to a `NVARCHAR` datatype

here's a similar example to what you're trying to to.

```
DECLARE @tableName          NVARCHAR(50) = 'Test';
DECLARE @iCounter           INT,
        @TSQL               NVarchar(Max);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Test(Id INT);
INSERT INTO dbo.Test(Id) VALUES(1);

SET @TSQL =
    N'
        SET @iCounter = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.'+@tableName +' )
    '
--PRINT @TSQL; 
--you pass the @iCounter as an OUTPUT parameter
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @TSQL, N'@iCounter INT OUTPUT', @iCounter OUTPUT
SELECT @iCounter
```